# PDO use quote with an array

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new in PDO

```
$sFields = "'".implode("', '", $fields)."'";
$sColumns = implode(", ", $columns);
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($sColumns) VALUES ($sFields)";
```

What is the shortest way to use PDO::quote  on each value I want to insert.

I tried

```
$fields = array_map('$bdd->quote', $fields);
```

but it returns:

> Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '$bdd->quote' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Hopefully you've properly escaped those fields/columns or you'll still be injecting yourself, PDO or no PDO...

Comment: I'm using stripslashes before the quote

Comment: stripslashes is the wet toilet paper of sql injection. it does NOTHING to protect you. pretend the function doesn't exist and use PROPER query construction methods. you're using PDO - use placeholders and prepared queries.

Comment: i'm using prepare but no placeholder, i'll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is other way than concat sql string.

```
$sColumns = implode(", ", $columns);
$sFields = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($fields), '?'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($sColumns) VALUES ($sFields)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($fields);
```

Comment: For security purpose this is the best solution. However, it does not answer the question in the OP. Oleg's answer does answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$fields = array_map(array($bdd, 'quote'), $fields);
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct. Documentation: https://php.net/language.types.callable