# pdo update work in xamp but not work in server

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I use this function to update a table.

It works correctly in xamp and local but on the server it returns this error:

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': WHERE `id`=1' at line

```
function update($sTable, $aValues = array(),$key,$debug = 0){

        global $pdo;
        unset($aValues['edit']);
        unset($aValues['update']);

        if (!empty($aValues) && !empty($sTable)){

            # validation of table / columns nam

            $aColumns = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_keys($aValues));

            $aElements = array();

            foreach ($aColumns as $sColumn){

                $aElements[] = "`$sColumn`= :$sColumn";

            } // foreach

            $oPDOStatement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $sTable SET " . implode(',', $aElements)." WHERE `id`=$key");

            $oPDOStatement->execute($aValues);

            if($debug==1) print_r($oPDOStatement->errorInfo());

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're mixing a `mysql_` function `mysql_real_escape_string()` with PDO, Those different APIs don't intermix together. The colon in `:$sColumn` could also be a factor.

Comment: Edit your question and print out the `update` statement after variable substitution.  My guess is that the syntax error will be obvious.

Comment: after all update error return . and "this function work correct in xamp and local but in server return this error"

Comment: @GordonLinoff Plus, mixing in an `mysql_` function doesn't help neither.

Comment: @Fred -ii what function can i use instead of mysql_ ???

Comment: We would need to know which API you're actually using to connect with. Is it `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, PDO?

Comment: @Fred -ii i using pdo $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost', 'root', '');

Comment: Hard to say, but have a look at these Q's and A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/22793617/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/14195032/ and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/q/11999343/